# Why Core Data doesnot save data when i re-launch the app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Why Core Data doesnot save data when i re-launch the app ?
When i add the data into managedObjects then it will save and show it in the View Controller But, when i terminate the app and again launch. Then it lost all the data within the Objects.

CoreData.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreData {

    static func save(name: String, keyPath: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Task", in: managedContext)!

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

        person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: keyPath)

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            task.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    static func fetch() {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")
        do {
            task = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
func saveDetail()
    {
        CoreData.save(name: tfCat.text!, keyPath: "category")
        //CoreData.save(name: tfTask.text!, keyPath: "task_name")
    }

@IBAction func btnCreate(_ sender: Any)
    {
        //Function used to save the details in Core Data Models
        self.saveDetail()
    }
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.


    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AddTask")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the objects you fetch.

Comment: Where does `task`come from? And why `setValue:forKeyPath`? And don't `guard` AppDelegate. Force unwrap it. Your app won't even launch if `AppDelegate` was missing.

Comment: ... and you are creating `Task` objects but fetching `Person` objects.

Comment: why my data not saved ?

Comment: @RahulChopra Your data might be saved correctly as `Task` objects, but it will not be reloaded if you fetch `Person` objects.